# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS return error

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I use nested MySQL query to get user posts, and when I put SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in child query, MySQL return error: `Incorrect usage/placement of 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS'`

The query is:

```
SELECT inner_table.*
  , users.username as last_username
  , posts.date_added as last_date_added
  , users.user_id as last_user_id
  , posts.date_added as last_post_date 
FROM (
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS topics.topic_id
      , topics.date_added
      , topics.title
      , topics.user_id
      , MAX(posts.post_id) as last_post
      , posts.user_id as post_user_id
      , users.username
      , topics.previews
      , topics.fcat_id
      , topics.is_important
      , topics.is_locked
      , topics.lastpost_time
      , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE posts.topic_id=topics.topic_id) as posts_cnt
    FROM topics
    LEFT JOIN users ON (users.user_id = topics.user_id)
    LEFT JOIN posts ON (topics.topic_id = posts.topic_id)
    WHERE topics.user_id = ".$this->session->getSession("user_data", "user_id")."
    OR ".$this->session->getSession("user_data", "user_id")."
    IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT user_id
      FROM posts
      WHERE posts.topic_id = topics.topic_id
    )
    GROUP BY topics.topic_id
    ORDER BY topics.lastpost_time DESC
    LIMIT ".$limit * $page.", ".$limit."
    ) as inner_table
LEFT JOIN `posts` ON (posts.post_id=inner_table.last_post)
LEFT JOIN `users` ON (users.user_id=posts.user_id)
ORDER BY inner_table.lastpost_time DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is allowed on an inside query.
Put in on the outer query instead.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS inner_table.*
  ....
```

Also you have an error in the last line:

```
ORDER BY inner_table.lastpost_time DES
```

Replace it with:

```
ORDER BY inner_table.lastpost_time DESC
```

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment the following work-around ideas.

Output the inner select into a temp table.

Using code like this:

```
/* do this once*/
CREATE TABLE `temp_table` LIKE SELECT topics.topic_id
      , topics.date_added ....

/*do this for every query*/
DELETE FROM temp_table WHERE temp_table.topic_id <> 0;
INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT topics.topic_id
  , topics.date_added
  , topics.title
.... /*!! without the limit clause !!*/
SELECT count(*) as rowcount FROM temp_table;

/*then use the temp_table in place of the inner select*/

SELECT inner_table.*
 , users.username as last_username
  , posts.date_added as last_date_added
  , users.user_id as last_user_id
  , posts.date_added as last_post_date 
FROM temp_table .....
LIMIT ....
```

Using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS doesn't work on an INSERT .. SELECT either, but the above code is a workaround, you can of course run the inner query separate with a `LIMIT 1` on it to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: No, this just was not copied. The error is another - Incorrect usage/placement of 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS'

Comment: I tried to put SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS on the outer query, but then returns me only count of LIMIT in inner query results.